# Avalonia C# app published with PublishAot flag still contains DLLs in the output directory

Tags: c#, avalonia, self-contained, ahead-of-time-compile

I have an app that uses NET8 and Avalonia and when I publish it with "Produce single file" flag and this flag in csproj `<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>` everything works as expected and I get a single exe file as a result.

But when I publish it with Native AOT enabled `<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>` (which is also implies compilation into a single file), I still have the following dlls in the output folder

```
av_libglesv2.dll
libHarfBuzzSharp.dll
libSkiaSharp.dll
```

Any way to pack these dlls into the exe?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net8plus%2Cwindows#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment check the limitations and check the output of the build process. There should be warnings if you run in to limitation/incompatibilities.